# Best way of learning Python + GUI when coming from .NET

Tags: python, gui, user-interface

I've been developing applications in **C#** / **VB.NET** for about 3-4 years (**.NET Framework** v2.0, 3.5, 4). I have also developed some command-line applications or scripts in C, and Python under Linux.

Sometimes I need to develop my applications in another languages, like **Python**, but the <strike>problem</strike> thing is that lots of those applications require a GUI. Maybe not a too complex one, but it does require some windows with *buttons*, *text boxes*, *list boxes*,...

What books/tips/tutorials do you suggest me to start working with that language and be able to deploy my deliverables not only in **.NET**?

**Note:**
Learning python is not the big deal here, because I already know the basic of it. I just want to focus on the GUI.

*Maybe this question should be on [UI](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) instead of here? If so, please, migrate it :)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Id suggest [Dive into Python 3](http://diveintopython3.org/) book. And this one for interface [Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html) if you prefer Qt, and [wxPython in Action](http://www.manning.com/rappin/) if wxWidgets are your tool of choice.

First book helped me a lot, but I have ended up with Ruby=))

Comment: The Qt Book is good

Comment: Thank you @Alexey for your answer. I will take a look at those books and I'll let you know.

Comment: let me ask you something: Does the final user needs to have QT/wsWidgets installed to run it?

Comment: You can try to start with this link http://arstechnica.com/open-source/guides/2009/03/how-to-deploying-pyqt-applications-on-windows-and-mac-os-x.ars/. Hope will help =)